# Change default behaviour of BindingList

Tags: c#, bindinglist

I'm working on BindingList, and I want to change it's default behaviour so that refreshing the DataGridView that its bounded to, is done when I manually raise the event. In my case I'm updating BindingList with data in the foreach loop on every 1 second, and after all contents are up to date i want to refresh the DataGridView. What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132734(v=vs.110).aspx) documentation, it looks like you can derive from `BindingList<T>` and override `BindingList<T>.SupportsChangeNotificationCore` to turn off list change notifications:

```
public class MyBindingList<T> : BindingList<T>
{
    protected override bool SupportsChangeNotificationCore 
    { 
        get { return false; } 
    }
}
```

and then you should be able to call `ResetBindings()` when you need to update your DataGridView.

However, if by "updating BindingList", you just mean adding/removing items, then you can set `BindingList<T>.RaiseListChangedEvents` to false in order to turn off list changed notifications:

```
var bindingList = new BindingList<string>();
bindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = false; // turn off notifications
bindingList.Add("foo"); // no notifications raised
...
bindingList.RaiseListChangedEvents = true; // turn on notifications
bindingList.ResetBindings(); // raise notifications
```

Comment: Overriding `BindingList<T>.SupportsChangeNotificationCor` does turn off the list change notifications but `ResetBinding()` doesn't work.

Comment: sorry, yes, I just created a test project and it looks like you need to set `RaiseListChangedEvents = true` before calling `ResetBindings`. Editing my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can:

1. use a [BindingSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource(v=vs.110).aspx) to wrap the bindinglist
2. the datagridView bind to bindingSource
3. set [BindingSource.RaiseListChangedEvents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.raiselistchangedevents(v=vs.110).aspx) = false, so ListChanged event are not raised (the datagrid dont listen to change)
4. update list
5. reset RaiseListChangedEvents and call [BindingSource.ResetBindings(false)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resetbindings(v=vs.110).aspx) to signal to all bound component to refresh data

usually you can also use [BindingSource.SuspendBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.suspendbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) to prevent changes, and [ResumeBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.resumebinding(v=vs.110).aspx) to resume, but that doesnt work with DataGridView, only with simple control like TextBox ( see [remarks on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.bindingsource.suspendbinding(v=vs.110).aspx) )